# How to access dynamic params in nextjs 13 middleware

Tags: next.js

I'm having trouble accessing the parameters of a route in the api routes middleware. It's possible do that?
I have the route /api/test/2. I would like to know if in the middleware api it is possible to access dynamic parameter 2 in this case :testId.

This is my middleware:

```
import { getToken } from "next-auth/jwt";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

const isApiRoute = (pathname: string) => {
  return pathname.startsWith("/api");
};

export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const token = await getToken({ req });
  const { pathname } = req.nextUrl;
  if (!token) {
    if (isApiRoute(pathname)) {
      return NextResponse.json(
        {
          message: "Unauthorized",
        },
        { status: 401 }
      );
    }
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/login", req.url));
  }
  return NextResponse.next();
}

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    "/api/test/:path*",
  ],
};
```

Someone can help me?

I would like to know if this is possible to do

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.